# how to get name of the node in boost::ptree (not the name of child, we know only the filename)

Tags: boost, boost-propertytree

When we parse any xml file, we got a ptree, but how to know name of the root node?
Or like when we pass a node as argument in a function, then how we can get the name of node in function.

Comment: For parsing XML, I'd suggest using an XML library. Boost Property Tree is NOT an XML library.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such way. If you have access to an ancestor (like, e.g. the tree root) you can use iteration to *find* it though.

See this answer for sample code:

- [C++: boost ptree relative key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255463/c-boost-ptree-relative-key)
- [Getting boost property_tree parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366768/getting-boost-property-tree-parent-node/45367258#45367258)

Answer (score -1):

You should know  name of the node in advance or you can find it out using loop

```
for (auto it : ptree)
{
    std::string name = it.first;
}
```

Comment: This will give the name of child of ptree (starting from attributes if present), I want to know the name of ptree.  like in libxml we can get the name by node->get_name(), it simply gives the name of the node